# XOR Magic Rectangle

Tags: java, matrix, xor

## The Problem:

In a magic rectangle of dimensions m x n, every entry is the XOR of the row and column, zero-indexed.
Example (8 x 5):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 0 3 2 5 4 7 6
2 3 0 1 6 7 4 5
3 2 1 0 7 6 5 4
4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3
```

I need to find the sum of every entry, however, brute-forcing will not work as inputs range in the 10s of millions.

## My work so far:

I found, that for a m x n matrix where the m or n is a power of 2, you can calculate the sum as sum_range(0, m-1) * n, where sum range literally just adds every number between the first and second input.

Things get interesting when neither m nor n is a power of 2.

You can split the m x n rectangle into a rectangle composed of sub m x n rectangles that *are* powers of two, like this: (15 x 15)

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 | 8, 9, 10, 11 | 12, 13 | 14 | 
1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6 | 9, 8, 11, 10 | 13, 12 | 15 | 
2, 3, 0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5 | 10, 11, 8, 9 | 14, 15 | 12 | 
3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4 | 11, 10, 9, 8 | 15, 14 | 13 | 
4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3 | 12, 13, 14, 15 | 8, 9 | 10 | 
5, 4, 7, 6, 1, 0, 3, 2 | 13, 12, 15, 14 | 9, 8 | 11 | 
6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1 | 14, 15, 12, 13 | 10, 11 | 8 | 
7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 | 15, 14, 13, 12 | 11, 10 | 9 | 
----------------------------------------------------
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 | 0, 1, 2, 3 | 4, 5 | 6 | 
9, 8, 11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14 | 1, 0, 3, 2 | 5, 4 | 7 | 
10, 11, 8, 9, 14, 15, 12, 13 | 2, 3, 0, 1 | 6, 7 | 4 | 
11, 10, 9, 8, 15, 14, 13, 12 | 3, 2, 1, 0 | 7, 6 | 5 | 
----------------------------------------------------
12, 13, 14, 15, 8, 9, 10, 11 | 4, 5, 6, 7 | 0, 1 | 2 | 
13, 12, 15, 14, 9, 8, 11, 10 | 5, 4, 7, 6 | 1, 0 | 3 | 
----------------------------------------------------
14, 15, 12, 13, 10, 11, 8, 9 | 6, 7, 4, 5 | 2, 3 | 0 | 
----------------------------------------------------
```

Then, using the formula I described above, you can get the sum of each of the squares along the diagonal (my explanation makes no sense so here is a picture):
[not enough reputation for embeds ._.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRxbw.png)

## And that's were I am

I don't understand how to get the sum of the other parts, in terms of m and n, without brute-forcing. **remember, m and n will be random integers, and they could be very very large**

I see some pattern, like how the magic rectangle has some symmetry, and that the sides are the numbers 0 - (m-1) in order, however, I fail to come up with logic to translate that into code.

Pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. Not, however, looking for code, as this is a code wars problem and that's cheating

Reference Problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59568be9cc15b57637000054/train/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can divide the matrix into four sub metrices and leverage `sum_range(start, m-1) * n` over and over. For simplicity I'll explain using recursion, you can easily convert it to non recursive solution using queue.

Let's consider small worse case scenario, a 7x7 matrix. Where, m=7(columns), n=7(rows). Sum 168.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7]
[2, 3, 0, 1, 6, 7, 4]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 7, 6, 5]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2]
[5, 4, 7, 6, 1, 0, 3]
[6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 0]
```

We can divide this matrix into following 4 matrices:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] [4, 5, 6, 7] [0, 1, 2]
[1, 0, 3, 2] [5, 4, 7] [5, 4, 7, 6] [1, 0, 3]
[2, 3, 0, 1] [6, 7, 4] [6, 7, 4, 5] [2, 3, 0]
[3, 2, 1, 0] [7, 6, 5]
```

Here first matrix has dimensions equal to maximum possible power of 2 which is 4. Rest are just remaining 3 parts of the parent matrix.
We can use the formula to get sum for first matrix: `rowSum*rows -> (m*(m-1)/2)*n -> (4*3/2)*4 -> 24`

Next we consider second sub matrix. And divide in 4 parts using same strategy:

```
[4, 5] [6] [6, 7] [4]
[5, 4] [7] [7, 6] [5]
```

Here, first sub matrix can be calculated using formula `(rowSum - startSum)*rows`->`((m*(m-1)/2) - (start*(start-1)/2)) * n` -> `(6*5/2 - 4*3/2)*2` -> `18`. Here, `start = 4 xor 0`.
From above discussion we can create recursive function like this:

```
int result = calculate(0,0,m,n);
System.out.println("Total: " + result);

int calculate(int m0, int n0, int m, int n) {
     System.out.print("calculating: (" +m0+","+n0 + ") (" + m +","+n+") ");

     if( (m0,n0) (m,n) is single dimensional array then)
            //use for loops do xor and return sum.

     //get maximum possible power of 2 that can be used to derive first sub matrix
     int pow = (int)(Math.log(m-m0) / Math.log(2));
     pow = (int)Math.pow(2, pow);
      
     //sum = sum(first sub matrix (m0,pow)(n0,pow))

     //sum += calculate(dimensions of second sub matrix)
     //sum += calculate(dimensions of third sub matrix)
     //sum += calculate(dimensions of fourth sub matrix)
    
     return sum;
}

int sum(int start, int m, int n) {
    m=m+start;
    int sum = (m*(m-1)/2);
    sum -= (start*(start-1)/2);
    sum *=n;
    System.out.println("sum="+sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Above code should yield output like:

```
calculating: (0,0) (7,7) sum=24
calculating: (4,0) (7,4) sum=18
calculating: (6,0) (7,2) sum=13
calculating: (4,2) (6,4) sum=26
calculating: (6,2) (7,4) sum=9
calculating: (0,4) (4,7) sum=66
calculating: (4,4) (7,7) sum=2
calculating: (6,4) (7,6) sum=5
calculating: (4,6) (6,7) sum=5
calculating: (6,6) (7,7) sum=0
Total: 168
```

To keep recursions minimum, make sure `m>n`. If it is not then swap the values.

Note: As per the author's request, not providing the working code.

Comment: Thanks so much! just to clarify- m0 and n0 are 0 indexed and m and n are 1 indexed?

Comment: I seem to be running into a recursion error. It works on smaller numbers but when m and n are in the tens of millions it hits maximum recursion depth

Comment: You can convert it to iterative solution using queue. Add first matrix, then run while loop till queue not empty. In side the loop take a matrix from head of queue get sum then add 3 sub matrices to the queue. Also, in my example second and third sub matrices are 3x4 and 4x3 respectively. They are identical. If you switch m and n for second matrix and make it 4x3. it will get calculated in one turn like the third matrix. This will save huge no of iterations.

Comment: I finally figured it out, however for submtraixes were one of the dimensions are 1, looping through every single one to xor it and add them up is much too slow. Do you have any idea on a pattern/formula that can be used here?
TIA for all of your help